# r markdown inline equation newline issue

Tags: r, r-markdown

I am using R markdown with `rmarkdown::render()`. The problem I am having is that all inline latex equations gets displayed in a new line in the resulting html document.

For example, the .Rmd file containing the following:

```
numeric observations $y_1,\dots y_T$ up to some time $T$
```

turns out line breaks before y_1  and before T.

Has anybody had this problem and/or knows how to fix it?

Thank you in advance,
Giovanni

Comment: Can you try using `$$` instead of single `$`?

Comment: But that gives a displyed equation. It works fine for its purpose, but it is not what I want.

Comment: When I knit (using the "knit" button) or `render` an `rmarkdown` document with just the line you posted, I don't get any line breaks, whether outputting to PDF or html.

Comment: I have just realized that I dont have this issue when opening the html file with Firefox, but I still do when I use Safari...